# Matching names between two columns of two dataframes and adding new columns to one - long computing time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

- df1 -> Dataframe of all german cities their names and more data.
- df2 -> Dataframe of all german cities and their longitude and latitude

I wrote a function that searches for  a city name in both dataframes and returns the longitude and latitude:

```
def ret_longlat(city_name):

    if sum(df_cities["city"] == city_name) > 0:
        long = df_cities["lon"][df_cities["city"] == city_name].iloc[0]
        lat = df_cities["lat"][df_cities["city"] == city_name].iloc[0]
    else:
        long = 0
        lat = 0
    return long,lat
```

In the next step I apply this function to all city names of df1 and save the result in a new Column:

```
df_result["long"] = df_result["city_names"].apply(lambda x: ret_longlat(x)[0])
df_result["lat"] = df_result["city_names"].apply(lambda x: ret_longlat(x)[1])
```

This whole process takes relatively long (I'd say 5 minutes for 12162 rows).

Is there a way to improve the code?

Example Data:

**df1**

```
        city        
1       stadtA  
2       stadtB  
3       stadtu  
4       stadty  
5       stadtX
```

**df2**

```
    city        lat         lon
14  stadtD      50.611879   12.135526
24  stadtA      48.698890   9.842890
25  stadtC      52.947222   12.849444
26  stadtB      52.867370   12.813750
27  stadtY      52.985000   12.854444
```

Comment: what's the final desired output?

Comment: the new columns for the df_result dataframe

Comment: we need to see what it should look like and what the input looks like

Comment: added input examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a merge problem. You can perform a left merge and then fill missing values:

```
res = pd.merge(df1.rename(columns={'city_names': 'city'}),
               df2[['city', 'long', 'lat']].drop_duplicates('city'),
               how='left', on='city')

res[['long', 'lat']] = res[['long', 'lat']].fillna(0)
```

Comment: I am getting : KeyError: "['lat'] not in index" -Added example df

Comment: @Phil, Which line?

Comment: In res[['long', 'lat']] = res[['long', 'lat']].fillna(0)

Comment: What do you  see for `res.columns`?

Comment: 'lat_x', 'lat_y'

Comment: That means `df1` already had `lat` and `long` columns **before** your merge. That's different to the input you specified in your question. Remove those columns from `df1` first if you don't need the old data.